# Component Won't Render on Map Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, logic, array-map

I'm using this component [progress](https://github.com/react-component/progress) to draw a progress line. It works when I hardcode the values, but when I use it inside a map function it does not pick up the values.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?.

```
import { Line, Circle } from 'rc-progress';

render(){ 

  const elements = [{'percent':10,'color':'#3FC7FA'}, {'percent':30,'color':'#85D262'},{'percent':80,'color': '#FE8C6A'}]
return (
  {elements.map((obj) => 
      <Line percent="{obj.percent}" strokeWidth="6" strokeColor="{obj.color}" trailWidth="6" /> 
   )}
)
}
```

Comment: `{elements.map(....)}` is a block with a single expression. It doesn't produce a value. This not JSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `return` statement:

```
render(){ 

  const elements = [{'percent':10,'color':'#3FC7FA'}, {'percent':30,'color':'#85D262'},{'percent':80,'color': '#FE8C6A'}]
  return elements.map((obj) => 
      <Line percent="{obj.percent}" strokeWidth="6" strokeColor="{obj.color}" trailWidth="6" /> 
   )
}
```

Comment: I do return it and the line is drawn but the stroke color and the percentage values do not appear.

Comment: Should be `percent={obj.percent}`. Same for `strokeColor`, remove the quotes of it's not a string. You should also provide a unique `key` prop.

Comment: oh my god..yeah it was the quotes!. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

Your render needs a return

```
import { Line, Circle } from 'rc-progress';

render(){ 

    const elements = [{'percent':10,'color':'#3FC7FA'},{'percent':30,'color':'#85D262'},{'percent':80,'color': '#FE8C6A'}]
    return elements.map((obj) => 
        <Line percent={obj.percent} strokeWidth="6" strokeColor={obj.color} trailWidth="6" /> 
}
```

The `elements.map()` isn't a single value, so, you should not use it inside `{}`. Just return the map on your `render()` method

> Pay atention: if you want to pass variables to your components props, don't use quotes. Do this: `<Line percent={obj.percent}/>` instead of `<Line percent="{obj.percent}"/>`

Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component